# Array storing in FORTRAN-90

Tags: arrays, sorting, fortran90

I am using FORTRAN-90.
I have one problem.

I want to store data (i.e. X and Y values) in an three dimensional array (A(900,900,900),B(900,900,900)) in such a way that at begining I used only 30X30X30 elements of each array for storage 30X30X30 initial values of X and Y and then at the next time step I have some scientific calculations to change the values of X and Y and then again want to store 30X30X30 modified values of X and Y in the same array from the (31X31X31)th position of the both arrays and again the same procedure for the next time step . In this way I want to fill the array with my data and finally want to print these arrays.

Could you please help me out how I can write this algorithim I FORTRAN code…..

Please help me.

Please guide me

With best regards

Amitavo

Comment: 11GB for double precision. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Besides the size issues, can you please post an example starting with a 3x3x3 array, and progressing to a 4x4x4 so we can understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you are never going to use the cross terms `A(1,31,31)` then you don't need all the `900x900x900` element. Only `30` sub matrices of `30x30x30` are used which is considerably less space needed.

Comment: Is `A` the `x` values and `B` the `y` values?

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about this:

```
real*8 :: A(900,900,900),X(30,30,30)
integer :: offset

offset=0

!   define X however ...

A(1:30,1:30,1:30)=X

do while (offset<900)
! do stuff to X
! do more stuff to X
  offset=offset+30
  A(1+offset:30+offset,1+offset:30+offset,1+offset:30+offset)=X
enddo
```

Also, I think ja72 has the better idea.  But if this is how you need to do it, I think this is what you want.